# How to test controller action that uses puntopagos and rest-client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, stub, rspec3

I have a controller with a POST action named `create`. In the create action I use a [puntopagos gem](https://github.com/acidlabs/puntopagos-ruby) class (`PuntoPagos::Request`) that uses the [rest-client gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to make a POST to an API:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def create
    request = PuntoPagos::Request.new
    response = request.create
    #request.create method (another method deeper, really)
    #does the POST to the API using rest-client gem.

    if response.success?    
      #do something on success
    else
      #do something on error
    end
  end

end
```

How can I, with RSpec, stub the rest-client request and response in order to test my create action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stub `PuntoPagos::Request.new` and keep on stubbing:

```
response = double 'response'
response.stub(:success?) { true }
request = double 'request'
request.stub(:create) { response }
PuntoPagos::Request.stub(:new) { request }
```

That's for a successful request; do it again with `success?` stubbed to return `false` to test that branch.

Once you've got that working, look in to [`stub_chain`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods) to do the same thing with less typing.

Having said that, it would be much better to extract the PuntoPagos stuff into a separate class with a simpler interface:

```
class PuntoPagosService
  def self.make_request
    request = PuntoPagos::Request.new
    response = request.create
    response.success?
  end
end
```

Then you can just do

```
PuntoPagosService.stub(:make_request) { true }
```

in your test.